# How useful is it to disable access time logging on SSD and are there disadvantages doing so?

Tags: ext4, fstab, ssd, atime

As SSD drives have limited writes, I would like to know whether disabling access time logging still plays a significant role in 2021. Most websites I see on the subject are from 2015 and before, and SSD might be more robust nowadays.

I don't really realise how SSD writes are managed on Linux systems with respect to cacheing, nor do I know how many files are actually concerned by those logs or whether all or only some of the accessed files are updated to include access times.

My final question concern the disadvantages of disabling access time logging. What services use access times? Will something break? Is there something I should know?

Thanks in advance!

PS: I am using Ubuntu 21.04 for daily usage on a 300 GB partition on SSD. My computer model was released mid-2020.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it. Even back in 2015 it took hundreds of TB worth of writes to break even the lower end SSD's with the better ones (Samsung) pushing past 2PB worth of writes.

It is unlikely that you are going to exceed maximum number of writes in a remotely realistic scenario but you could look up the model number and check the manufacturer's stated max. writes.

PS. On a normal HDD writes aren't free either. The drive is mechanical and writing (and reading) requires the head to to the correct position, causing wear.

Comment: """What services use access times? Will something break? Is there something I should know?""" -- My comment is, I can't name any, but envision some properly paranoid security models where a supervising tripwire style application is engaged in ensuring that read-only access has not been invoked by an unscheduled operation. Personally I try to architect against this sort of usage case, but for the sake of potentially needing to do forensics, I tend to leave noatime off the mount statement, hardware lifetime potentially or certainly shortened, sure.

Comment: Thank you @sjaak, this was super helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of optimizations in the kernel and ext4 to reduce the overhead of atime updates, such as `relatime` (only update atime when it is older than mtime or more than a day old) and `lazytime` (delay atime updates and aggregate writes of multiple inodes in a single block only when needed or if more than a day old).

The cheapest consumer-grade flash device are rated at 1 full Drive Write Per Day (DWPD) for 3 years.  Inodes are typically 1/32 or less of the blocks in the filesystem, so the atime updates of inodes (limited to one atime write per day) are not going to be the deciding factor for exceeding the DWPD of the device.

Answer (score -2):

Just the obvious

Advantages:

By not updating every file's access time (`atime`) one produces fewer writes to "disk" to update the inode.

Disadvantages:

One cannot make use of `atime` to learn a file's access time.

A file's access time is not a widely used "thing". Creation time (`ctime`) and modification time (`mtime`) are more useful.

Back when there was no limit on disk writes, updating `atime` was essentially "free".

Using the `atime` value lets one see which, of a set of files, have been accessed (read, but not modified) recently, or not recently.

Security investigations, checking to see if all the important files were read,... those are the only uses of `atime` that spring to mind.

Comment: `ctime` is not creation time, it's inode (metadata) change time

Comment: `atime` is useful for locally-stored email.

Comment: When is inode actually changed?

Comment: "`ctime` shows when your file or directory got metadata changes – typically that’s file ownership (username and/or group) and access permissions. ctime will also get updated if the file contents got changed." Thank you @roaima for pointing this out, I didn't know either!

Comment: @JohannesLemonde `chmod` and `chown` will update `ctime`. Consider the `mtime` and `ctime` values resulting from this sequence: `touch x; stat x; sleep 30; touch x; stat x; sleep 30; chmod o=u x; stat x`